# How to proper label a plot

Tags: graphing-functions, publishing

This is somewhat a dumb question but in an article I have some function, say $f$, that depends of the variable $x$. Let's take for example the function $f$ to be given by:
$$f(x)=a \log(\frac{x}{a}),$$ where $a$ is a parameter.

I now want to plot the function $f$. Since $a$ is a parameter my plot should have on the horizontal axis $x/a$ but then on the vertical axis should I label it as $\frac{1}{a} f(x)$ or  $\frac{1}{a} f(\frac{x}{a})$?

I hope it's clear what I want to say. If it's confusing please let me know and i'll post some images.

Comment: “Since $a$ is a parameter my plot should have on the horizontal axis $x/a$”. Why in the world?  The horizontal axis' name is the name of the first coordinate in a Cartesian system.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Maybe I should have add that I wanted to show the behaviour of the function not the exact value since the parameter $a$ is some value given by experiment. So I should plot the function  in terms of $x/a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\frac{1}{a}f(x) = \log \left(  \frac{x}{a} \right)$ is correct.

Another way of achieving what you are asking for, where $y=\left( \frac{x}{a} \right) ^{a}$, found using basic rules of manipulating logarithms.

$$
f(y) = \log(y) = \log \left(  \left( \frac{x}{a} \right) ^{a} \right)
$$

Personally,I would not go down this route as it complicates an otherwise simple looking function. I would use multiple line plots on the same axis with various determined values of $a$ labelled with a legend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I may add, though, that in my specific case the function is actually much more complicated than my example, notwithstanding, your answer disperses my doubts.

Comment: Understood. You may be interested that in many applied fields such as physics and engineering, they achieve this through dimensional analysis and make plots using dimensionless numbers as the variables (dimensionless in the sense they have no physical dimension).

Comment: That's exactly my case. This question arose when writing a physics homework. In my case the congenerous of the $x$ and $a$ have dimension of length. I should study more on that. Thank you for the key words.